# Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, on Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test

Why do I encounter or further explanation about the error?

> System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Error: You can't select products until you've chosen a price book for this opportunity on the products related list.: []

```
    Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
Product2 prod = new Product2(
            Name = 'Product X',
            ProductCode = 'Pro-X',
            isActive = true
        );
        insert prod;

        PricebookEntry pbEntry = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = pricebookId,
            Product2Id = prod.Id,
            UnitPrice = 100.00,
            IsActive = true
        );
        insert pbEntry;

        Pricebook2 customPB = new Pricebook2(
            Name='Custom Pricebook',
            isActive=true
        );
        insert customPB;

        Opportunity oppo = new Opportunity();
            oppo.StageName      = 'native acvise';
            oppo.Name           = '3';
            oppo.WFCE__WP_ID__c = '13';
            oppo.WFCE__Tax_Amount__c = 3;
            oppo.Pricebook2Id = pricebookId;
            oppo.CloseDate      = Date.today();
        insert oppo;

        OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
            OpportunityId = oppo.Id,
            Quantity = 2,
            Product2Id  = prod.Id,
            PricebookEntryId = pbEntry.Id,
            TotalPrice = 0
        );
        insert oli;
```

Comment: Can you tell us which line throws this error?

Comment: don't set the product2Id on OpportunityLineItem; SFDC does this for you automatically. Only set the PricebookEntryId

Comment: I do that but still got the error

Comment: thanks, guys I just solve my issue it states that I forgot to insert a required field from the custom setting

Comment: cropredy's comment is a lifesaver... I was cloning OpportunityLineItem and had no idea what was going on. +1 buddy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error states that you must choose a price book on the opportunity first. In a unit test, this usually involves using the Test.getStandardPricebookId method:

```
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
opp.Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
...
insert opp;
```

Comment: I do choose a price book for my opportunity but still got the error,

Comment: @gourdian And how would we know this without seeing any code? Can you please edit your question to include enough code so we don't have to make as many assumptions?

Comment: I updated now my codes.

Comment: thanks, guys I just solve my issue it states that I forgot to insert a required field from the custom setting